# Renaming a list of files in OS X

Tags: excel, macos, unix, scripting

I need to rename a list of files (sometimes up to 500) in OS X, what I´ve found is that pasting the list of files and their new names make the OS X console choke if over 25 files are being renamed, let me explain my process. I receive a bunch of files with a certain name, plus an Excel file that relates files names and student ID numbers, one document per student, so I rename them using `cp` like this (templated info):

```
cp documentNamedInExcel renamedFiles/studentIDsuffix.pdf
```

where suffix is the kind of document (grades report, studies record, etc), and so on for each document, I do this using `=CONCATENATE("cp ", A2, " renamedFiles/", E2, "suffix.pdf")` where A is the column where original document names reside and E is the column where students IDs reside, then I fill down the concatenate and create a list of cp´s, one for each document, then I copy these cp´s into a OS X console window, it would work perfect if it wash´t because the console chokes with plus 25 cp´s and misses some of the files, so, I have to paste no more than 25 cp´s each time, when you have 100-120 to rename is Ok, but when you have 500 this is kind of troublesome, how can I stream this process? detail! the files are not originally named following a pattern, thanx i.a. for your ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a bash script `file.sh` with the commands that you want to run. For example

```
#!/bin/bash
cp documentNamedInExcel renamedFiles/studentIDsuffix.pdf
cp ... ...
```

After exiting, make the script executable with: `chmod +x file.sh`. Then execute with `file.sh`